# Путь к изображениям в JSP

Tags: java, jsp, url, img, сервлеты

Когда я в web.xml указываю  корень проекта "/" то при попытке отобразить картинку в JSP не получается, а как только я через фильтр делаю редирект на /signIn, то картинка отображается.

```
---структура такая---
webappp
 -> images
   -> default.jpeg
 -> WEB-INF
   -> views
     -> signIn.jsp

---в браузэре---
при загрузке на   cars/         ничего не показывает
при редиректе на  /cars/signin/ показывает

---url в <img src="images/default.jpeg">---
```

Хотелось бы понять, почему именно так?

Comment: Указывайте полный путь от корня и все будет окей.

Comment: Как я только не указывал и /images/default.jpeg и ../../images/default.jpeg и ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/default.jpeg и не только

Answer (score 0):

Изначально на JSP странице картинку отображаю так:

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/default.jpeg
```

Какой у вас contextPath?

Comment: При переходе на /cars/signin/ url и при src="images/default.jpeg" у меня все показывает, а вот когда убираю редирект и гкд становится просто cars/ то даже ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/default.jpeg не работает

Comment: И все же, какой ContextPath? Куда деплоится приложение? Посмотрите в IDEA Run/Debug Config -> <сервер> -> вкладка Deployment -> Application context

Comment: @Моренець вот такой /cars